# Допоможіть перекласти "медведь-шатун"

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, from-russian

Не можу знайти нормального перекладу російського "медведь-шатун".

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Цей сайт **не є сайтом перекладів**, він є про українську мову. Тому наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання про переклад містило: (1) пояснення **своїми словами** іншомовного слова; (2) **контекст**, в якому автор збирається використовувати перекладене слово; (3) продемонструвати власну спробу знайти відповідь і (4) пояснити, чим са́ме знайдені варіанти не підходять. Запитання, які не відповідають цим умовам, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді.

Comment: Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Answer (score 3):

#### Про ведмедів, що взимку не перебувають у стані сплячки

«Російсько-український словник наукової термінології: біологія, хімія, медицина» С. Вассера (Київ, «Наукова думка», 1996) [пише](//books.google.com/books?id=EakeAQAAIAAJ&q=%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD):

> **шату́н** *биол. (бродячий зимой медведь)* шату́н, -на́

Іноді саме так уживається в художній літературі:

- > Взимку дід писав про ведмедя-шатуна. Мабуть, потурбували ненароком клишоногого в барлозі, ось і пішов вештатися тайгою. А шатун — він завжди шатун. Лихо — поряд. Довелося «нагодувати» жаканом господаря тайги. //В. Землянин, «Амба»
- > Я зирк — поряд з'являється ще один ведмідь-шатун. //В. Яр, «Записки Івана Карповича Мотихи — невизнаного поета, прозаїка, філософа, ще й комерсанта надодачу»
- > А ти-то чого лісом шатуном тиняєшся? //В. Тарасов, «Чеслав. В темряві сонця», 2012
- > Обернувся — брунатна туша повільно наближається до нього. Ведмідь! Шатун! Звідки вони в цих краях? Забрів невідомо звідкіля. Глухий рик, повільний крок… У цей час вони особливо злі, не знають спокою й сну. <…> Заклавши сокиру за пояс і схопивши піку, Федот потягнувся до гілки старого дерева, ногами підпер стовбур і рвонув угору. Піднявся й поліз вище. Дякувати Богові, вітер піддував з іншого боку й шатун не відчув його. Чоловік заліз якнайвище, причаївся. Брунатна пляма виднілася на мармуровому тлі. Звір обминув дерево, де сховався Федот, і наблизився до снігового горбика. <…> Добре, що в падінні Шевченко встиг вихопити сокиру й направити її лезом від себе, інакше він розпоров би власне черево: безглузда й випадкова смерть. Щойно він приземлився, як почув дикий, глухий рик. Шатун повільно йшов на двох лапах у його бік, а потім зненацька з тупуватим гуркотом опустився на чотири й побіг на чужинця. <…> Кривава слина розлетілася з пащі — від болю ведмідь прикусив язика і став ще злішим. Шатун загарчав. Спочатку тихо, потім дужче. <…> А той розгорнув гвинтівку й встромив штика прямо тварині в око. Шатун завив, шарпонув лапою чужорідне тіло, через що відчув нестерпний біль. Пролунав рик, сповнений убивчого страждання, потім стогін, хрип, сопіння. //М. Бутченко, «Куркуль», 2017
- > Так ось, на волі взимку ти спати не будеш, будеш тинятись холодний і голодний, безпритульний — лігво в тебе ж так само не підготовлене. А таких ведмедів називають шатунами. Вони злі, шкідливі. Люди таких ведмедів не люблять, роблять на них облави. //П. Місько в перекладі М. Онуфрійчука, «Ерпіди на планеті Земля», 1989

#### У загальному значенні

Загалом російське *шатун* перекладають як *шве́ндя*, *шве́ндяло*, *волоцю́га* ([«Російсько-український словник» Бусела](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/ru-uk/%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD)), *ве́штанець* ([«Російсько-український словник» Кримського і Єфремова](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on)), *ди́нда*, *шва́йкало* ([«Словарь української мови» Грінченка](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD&scope=all&dicts=12&highlight=on)), *заволо́ка* ([«Словарь російсько-український» Уманця і Спілки](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD&scope=rusb&dicts=9&highlight=on)). Але у випадку техніки — *шату́н*, *го́нок*, *косогі́н* ([«Російсько-український словник» Бусела](https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/ru-uk/%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD)), *корбові́д* ([«Російсько-український словник з інженерних технологій» Ганітчевич і Кінаша](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD&scope=all&dicts=17&highlight=on)). Можливо, слово *шатун* у випадку ведмедя теж можна вважати сталим терміном, як і у випадку деталі механізмів.

#### Про етимологію і розвиток мови

Власне, я розумію бажання позбутися гнізда *-шат-*, адже в сучасній українській мові воно стало майже чужорідним. На зміну йому прийшли безліч сучасніших і вживаніших синонімів: *ве́штатися*, *шве́ндяти* тощо. Однак насправді слово *[шата́тися](http://sum.in.ua/s/shatatysja)* має праслов'янське походження — від **šętati sę* з тим самим значенням ([«Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах, том 6, с. 175](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom6.pdf#page=175); [Англійський Вікісловник](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#Etymology)). Я не знаю, як називали тих особин, які взимку не в стані сплячки, у ті часи, коли ведмеді ще були поширені на теренах України — але зараз бурий ведмідь (єдиний вид з родини ведмедевих, що представлений на території України) [занесений у Червону книгу України, як зникаючий вид (залишилося менше 300 особин)](https://redbook-ua.org/item/ursus-arctos-linnaeus/), тому потреба називати їх фактично зникла.

Цікаво було б з'ясувати, що думають про це старожили областей (Закарпатської, Івано-Франківської, Львівської, Чернівецької), де ведмеді ще трохи збереглися — можливо, вони застали ті часи, коли ведмедів-шатунів ще якось називали.

Comment: Перепрошую, але -1: погані запитання мають закриватися, а не отримувати відповіді.

Answer (score 2):

І справді онлайн перекладачі пропонують варіант "ведмідь-шатун" і в українській мові і справді є слово "[шатун](http://sum.in.ua/s/shatun)". Однак, як бачимо воно означає:

> Рухома деталь кривошипних та деяких інших механізмів, що перетворює
>   зворотно-поступальний рух поршня на обертальний рух колінчастого вала
>   чи кривошипа.

Нічого спільного із ведмедями, проте [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%8C_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9) пише про "ведмедів-шатунів":

> В деякі роки, через неврожай основних кормів, ведмеді не встигають
>   восени достатньо відгодуватись, і взимку не залягають в сплячку. Через
>   те вони стають бездомними «шатунами», і є дуже небезпечними для людини
>   при зустрічі.

Як бачимо, в українській мові є слово "[шататися](http://sum.in.ua/s/shatatysja)" від якого і походить "шатун", тому гадаю, що казати ведмідь-шатун можна (однак, врахуйте, що коло слова "шататися" стоїть позначка "розмовне").

В Словнику синонімів мені не вдалося знайти жодної інформації про слово "шатун". Проте, я натрапив на цю статтю на сайті [Еnguide](https://enguide.ua/ua/magazine/kogda-perevod-mozhet-prichinyat-bol), де йшлося про переклад імені одного із персонажів твору Толкіена "Strider". І, здається, там є декілька непоганих варіантів, які можна було б використати, щоб замінити слово "шатун":

[Бродяга](http://sum.in.ua/s/Brodjagha):

> Бездомна людина, що не має постійного місця проживання, сталого
>   заняття, роботи.

[Блукач](http://sum.in.ua/s/blukach) (однак, тут є позначка рідко):

> Той, хто блукає, не має постійного місця проживання; бурлака.

[Колоброд](http://sum.in.ua/s/kolobrodyty) (від слова "колобродити"):

> Безцільно ходити, не зосереджуючись ні на чому; бродити, тинятися

Comment: Перепрошую, але -1: погані запитання мають закриватися, а не отримувати відповіді.